# Magento: filtering products based on multiple categories (or tags)

Tags: magento

I have a category tree that is not a tree. In fact I have something like:

```
                      man                                           woman
       summer2013      |      winter2013                             ...
shoes | shirts | bags            ...                                 ...
```

and, in addition, I have a filter by materials (`leather`, `plastic`, etc)

I would like that filters could be switched on and off, while I keep on navigating the tree. For example I would like to see all products for man in leather(ex: `/man?tag=leather)`, or all bags of summer 2013 in leather (ex: `/man/summer2013/bags?tag=leather`). I would also like that if I have `leather` turned on, my link to `man` adds also a query string to find only leather products.

Do you think it's possible?

Answer (score 0):

I was using this extension for switching on and off:
http://www.aitoc.com/en/magentomods_layered_navigation_pro.html?gclid=CKzisIzvk7gCFUhb3godPBAA8Q

The problem is that you want all categories to be visible all the time and this will not work out of the box. You would need to modify categories list to show all of them. It is not an easy task but this should be possible.